# Can someone ELI5 the difference between these two lines of code?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

```
1)
SKSpriteNode *node = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:image];

2)
node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];
```

I've seen code examples using both ways and I'm not sure what is best and why. What does exactly "alloc" stands for in the 1) case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one declares the variable `node` and uses a variable named `image`:

```
SKSpriteNode *node = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:image];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                ^^^^^
```

The second one assumes the variable `node` already exists, and uses a string literal:

```
node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];
                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Assuming you are using Automatic Reference Counting, or “ARC” (which you almost certainly are), **there is no significant difference** between using `[[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:...]` and using `[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:]`.

If you've disabled ARC in your project, or for this source file, then the difference is that `alloc/init...` returns a +1 reference that you must `release` or `autorelease` at some point, while `spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` returns an autoreleased reference that you must `retain` if you want to keep it around. If you want more details about manual memory management in Cocoa, start by reading [*Cocoa Core Competencies: Memory management*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1).